# Verification link in the email template in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: phoenix-framework

- I have set up accordingly to this tutorial: [Adding an Email
  Verification Flow With Phoenix](https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/09/06/adding-email-verification-flow-with-phoenix)
- However, it doesn't show how to set up a verification link in which
  `username`, `email`, and `token` are to be sent back to the backend
  so that email can be verified.

So take a peek inside the hex.pm source code to see how it is done.

```
<!-- verification.html.eex --> 
<%
verify_url = Routes.email_url(Endpoint, :verify, username: @username, email: @email, key: @key)
%>
```

- I am not sure with `Routes.email_url`. So I read through [More on
  Path Helpers](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#path-helpers), but still don't get it well.

**I want to know is how I can return an URL like above.**

This is what I have in my `router.ex`.

```
get "/verify", UserController, :verify_email
```

What else is needed? One thing is it seems I need to set up this in one of the modules or controllers.

```
alias MyApp.Web.Router.Helpers, as: Routes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way and it works. But I still am not sure where to put the alias for Route, so I just use Router.Helpers.

```
<!-- router.ex --> 
get "/verify", EmailController, :verify

<!-- verification.html.eex --> 
<% verify_url = MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.email_url(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :verify, uuid: @uuid) %>

<!-- email_controller.ex --> 
def verify(conn, %{"uuid" => uuid}) do
end
```